# Track/id detection like Shazam (Clip to short)

Tags: audio, vocals, audio-restoration

i found a nice melody on a German documentation.
How can i find more information about the melody ?

I tried to recognize it with shazam, but the problem is the part is only around 1sec long, on the other time the moderator is talking and its impossible to use this for shazam.

The total clip is 48 seconds long. Im sure a human can identifie the artist/name because he would recognize the melody.

I uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZO1rbp5bb2nkAdgbIMWbSAyk3ntCXcT-/view?usp=sharing
Perhaps someone knows the artist/name.

Are there any services/forums when i can upload the clip?

I tried to contact the producer company/publisher, without luck.

Thanks guys!

Comment: For some reason I can't play the clip - but things like documentary music are almost always from music library companies. No shazam-like app will ever be able to recognise them, because no-one ever takes the time to catalogue them all. Usually your only hope is to get the info from production.

Comment: @Tetsujin can you visit the link ? With what browser your tried to play it ?
My hope was the used beats from a "no-name" producer, but then your right: no one has index these...